# iPad exhibits and causes packet loss on Wifi

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

I'm having problems with Wifi on my iPad 6th generation (13.6). Especially in conferencing apps like Discord or Zoom, I have frequent lags where audio+video stops for 5-20 seconds. This happens almost every minute. Also in streaming apps like Netflix or Spotify or just browsing in Safari, I see frequent hangups where nothing happens for 5-20 seconds. When I perform a dedicated speedtest, bandwidth is perfectly normal though.

**The weird thing is:** I have absolutely no Wifi problems on my iPhone 6s (13.6) nor my laptop (Thinkpad T480s on Ubuntu 18.04). The iPad is propped up on the standard Apple cover, so its antennas should not be blocked. Conferencing apps and browsing works flawlessly on all devices except my iPad.

I assume the iPad is loosing packages and loads the Wifi 100% during the lag. Why? When I experience a lag on my iPad, all my other devices are unable to reach the internet too.
For example I monitored latency to 8.8.8.8 from my laptop while watching a stream on Discord on my iPad. When my iPad lags, my laptop can't reach 8.8.8.8 anymore (100% packet loss). After the lag (when audio/video continues) my laptop goes back to normal ping.

I have a Fritzbox 7360 on the newest firmware. I am the only network on the Wifi channel. I don't have a 5GHz network, 2.4GHz only.

I have already talked with Apple support but they were not helpful. I have already performed a 1) reset of network settings and also 2) a full factory reset without success. I would like to avoid sending in the iPad to avoid the long wait (Covid-19) and cost (no AppleCare).

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: It is *possible* that there is a hardware issue with this device. But before determining that I would reset the iPad and restore to factory defaults using iTunes. And then with (little or...) nothing installed try again. If it is still glitchy I would be tempted to blame the hardware. An Apple store could likely diagnose this issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have already performed a factory reset without success. If it is indeed a hardware problem, will I have to pay for the repair / replacement, despite having no Apple Care? I've bought the iPad ~14 months ago.